# Is there a reason I should NOT serialize my (Moose) objects using Storable or YAML?

Tags: perl, serialization, moose, kiokudb

I have a few Moose objects and some other simple hash objects (hashes, arrays) I'd like to serialize.

At first, I used a simple

```
my $obj_store_file = nstore($obj);
```

and

```
my $obj = retrieve($obj_store_file);
```

This worked well.

Later, I found about `MooseX::Storage` and `KiokuDB`. I tried using them to enjoy some benefits they have, but:

- `MooseX::Storage` seemed to recreate objects that are referred multiple times. For example, one of my serialized objects contains a few attributes, which each of them refers to the same instance of another object. Before serialization, all of these reference are obviously the same -- they all point to the same object. After serialization/de--serialization using `MooseX::Storage`, this once single object is duplicated and each reference points to another instance of the object. I was told that `MooseX::Storage` is not appropriate to represent object graphs and that I might want to try `KiokuDB`.
- I did, although I felt `KiokuDB` is an overkill for my needs. I don't need all the fancy stuff a DB can offer. Unfortunately, since one of my objects is really large and choaks on memory when serialized using defaults, it seems I have to write a custom serializer or store its 'data' portion separately then write a costume `KiokuX::Module`... again, quite an overkill.

So, I'm back to plain ol' Storable or YAML. My question is simple: yes, there are some benefits for `KiokuDB` (especially the fact it maintains an object graph) and perhaps also for `MooseX::Storage` (although I couldn't really find any for the latter). But, given these benefits are not really of use to me, is there any reason ***not*** to use Storable or YAML?

In other words, is there anything wrong with storing a (Moose) object this way? Is it 'illegal'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is that it depends on why you're serializing data. I like Storable for program state including things like window size/position. I prefer YAML for configuration data or anything you might want to exchange with another copy of the application. (i.e. share between users -- a Storable file might not be readable by a user with a different version of Perl or Storable.) Storable supports object graphs (assuming that the freeze/thaw is done correctly). I'm not sure about YAML.

Comment: I'm storing the objects just for my own later use. I do not want to recreate them each time (some of them require some heavy preprocessing). What I like about YAML is the ability to look at the stored file itself. It's nice to see what's going on in there. It seems YAML also supports object graphs - it uses internal pointers, but what bothers me is why won't it auto-load the needed classes.